# How to load Dynamic lazy loaded JS chunk in build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-lazy-load

**Issue I am facing**
After creating a build when I serve the application, the dynamic import chunks are missing a `/` in request URL.

Instead of loading `https://example.com/adminapp_routes_Dashboards_DashboardPage_js.chunk.js`, it should request for `https://example.com/admin/app_routes_Dashboards_DashboardPage_js.chunk.js` which is available on server but I'm getting 404.

**In React app**
Currently, I've added `lazy` imports.

```
const DashboardPage = lazy(() => import('./Dashboards/DashboardPage'))
```

Which is generated as a seperate chunk in `dist` called `app_routes_Dashboards_DashboardPage_js.chunk.js`

**Webpack Configuration**

```
const BASE_PATH = '/admin'
const distDir = path.join(root, "dist")
const srcDir = path.join(root, "app")
module.exports = {
  devtool: false,
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    app: [path.join(srcDir, 'index.js')],
  },
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'named',
    chunkIds: 'named',
    minimize: true,
    nodeEnv: 'production',
    mangleWasmImports: true,
    removeEmptyChunks: false,
    mergeDuplicateChunks: false,
    flagIncludedChunks: true,
    minimizer: [`...`, 
    new CssMinimizerPlugin({
      minimizerOptions: {
        preset: [
          "default",
          {
            calc: false,
            discardComments: { removeAll: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
    '...'],
    emitOnErrors: true,
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      minSize: 20000,
      minRemainingSize: 0,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 30,
      maxInitialRequests: 30,
      enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    path: distDir,
    publicPath: BASE_PATH,
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: { "querystring": false },
    modules: ['node_modules', config.srcDir],
    alias: {
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/components'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      exclude: /a\.js|node_modules/,
      failOnError: true,
      allowAsyncCycles: false,
      cwd: process.cwd(),
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: config.srcHtmlLayout,
      inject: 'body',
      title: 'Example',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
        BASE_PATH: JSON.stringify(BASE_PATH),
      },
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerMode: 'disabled' }), //* switch mode to server to active  BundleAnalyzerPlugin
    new PurgeCSSPlugin({ paths: glob.sync(`${path.resolve(__dirname, '../app')}/**/*`,  { nodir: true }) }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [config.srcDir, config.pluginsDir],
        exclude: /(node_modules|\.test\.js$)/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        sideEffects: false,
      },
      {
        test: /\.test\.js$/,
        include: [config.srcDir, config.pluginsDir],
        use: 'ignore-loader',
      },
      // Modular Styles
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
        exclude: [path.resolve(config.srcDir, 'styles')],
        include: [config.srcDir],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
        include: [path.resolve(config.srcDir, 'styles')],
      },
      // Fonts
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '/fonts/[name].[ext]',
          esModule: false,
        },
      },
      // Files
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '/static/[name].[ext]',
          esModule: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: false,
    //contentBase: config.distDir,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: BASE_PATH,
    },
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 4100,
  },
}
```